# Why UI Components do not load from Prefabs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made it so there should be a Text in front of the player displaying his health as you can see in the photo, I've done that by creating a canvas with World Space render.

The problem is that I made the Enemy a prefab with the text as a child and when I instantiate him in the scene he comes without the text, but if I click and drop him to the scene it works just right.

Here is the code for my Enemy and the spawner:

**Enemy:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemyControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text HealthText;
    public int Health = 20;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        UpdateLifeDisplay();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Death();
        UpdateLifeDisplay();
    }

    public void Death()
    {
        if(Health < 0)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }

    }

    void UpdateLifeDisplay()
    {

        if (HealthText != null)
        {
            HealthText.text = Health.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("LifeDisplay null");
        }
    }

}
```

**SpawnScript**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnHandle : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Upgrades
    public GameObject[] Upgrades;
    private int counter = 0;

    public Transform SpawnPoint;
    public Transform locA, locB;


    //Enemy
    public GameObject enemyPref;
    public Transform[] eSpawn;
    private int Ecounter = 0;




    void Start()
    {
        counter++;
        Ecounter++;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, Upgrades.Length );
            int randomIndex2 = Random.Range(0, Upgrades.Length );

            Instantiate(Upgrades[randomIndex], locA.position, SpawnPoint.rotation);
            Instantiate(Upgrades[randomIndex2], locB.position, SpawnPoint.rotation);

            counter = 0; 
            StartCoroutine(increase());
        }

        if (Ecounter > 0)
        {

            int randomE = Random.Range(0, 2);

            Instantiate(enemyPref, eSpawn[randomE].position, SpawnPoint.rotation);

            Ecounter = 0; 
            StartCoroutine(EnemyCounter());
        }

    }


    void spawn()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator increase()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
        counter++;
    }

    IEnumerator EnemyCounter()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.33f);
        Ecounter++;
    }
}
```

In the photo you can see the prefab

[image]

UI

[image]

Code for the text:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FloatingText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform mainCam;
    public Transform target;
    public Transform worldSpaceCanvas;
    public Vector3 offset;


    private void Start()
    {
        mainCam = Camera.main.transform;
        transform.SetParent(worldSpaceCanvas);

    }
    void Update()
    {

        if (target == null)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            return;
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - mainCam.transform.position); // look at camera

        transform.position = target.position + offset;
 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the UI component being added into the scene and simply not displaying or is it not being added at all?

Also make sure that your UI component is the child of a Canvas.

Comment: The UI is not being added at all, when is Instantiate my Enemy gameObject does not have the Text child.

Comment: Strange, could you send a screenshot of your prefab's structure so I can take a closer look?

Comment: Sure, should I edit the post and attach the photo?

Comment: Yes please, thanks :)

Comment: I hope that is good, thank you for the help !

Comment: Just seen your photo, there are no UI components on your prefab? Can you double click the prefab inside the Asset tab and show me the full structure so I can see whereabouts your UI components are? Thanks

Comment: So it looks like your HealthText GameObject is seperate from the Enemy GameObject, though that might not be the case.
If so, I would recommend having the HealthText object as a child of the Enemy prefab, this way when the Enemy prefab is instantiated, a HealthText is created alongside it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Just seen your new photo, are you certain the enemyPref variable on the Spawner references the prefab itself and not an Enemy already in the scene?

Comment: That's what I did but when I start the game I made it so it is going inside the WorldSpaceCanvas, I just attached the code inside the text. I just realised that this was important.

Yes, the prefab is attached.

Comment: Ok so it looks like two of the HealthText GameObjects have no parents, this could be due to the worldSpaceCanvas variable not having a value in the prefab?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by  variable not having a value in the prefab.

I modified it so the object have as parent the enemy but the same result, what I've just seen is that the text when is initialised  no longer have the WorldSpaceCanvas in the Inspector.

The transform is set to None.

Comment: I'm heading home soon, would you be able to export your project and I'll take a look when I get back? If you go to the Asset tab, select everything and right click->export package. If you could tell me the version of Unity you are using also that would be great, I'll do my best to help out

Comment: I manage to solve the problem by making a 3D text instead, Thank you for helping me, I really appreciate that !

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working